# session store does not store data

Tags: node.js, session, express

So, I am developing REST APIs, I am using express, mongojs, connect-mongo. and I am not able to figure out how to store the data in session:

```
var express = require('express'),
mongojs = require("mongojs"), 
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
GLOBAL.db = mongojs.connect(databaseUrl, collections);   
app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.session({
            key: 'express.sid',
            secret: 'secret',
            maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
            store: new MongoStore({ db: databaseUrl, collection: 'sessions' })
        }));
        app.use(app.router);
        app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
     });
```

The user attempts to login using:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:2048/auth  -d @./sampleData/authUser.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cookie myCookie.txt
```

When the user logs in successfully I do:

```
req.session.user = {}
req.session.user.id = currentUser._id.toString()
req.session.user.userame = currentUser.username
req.session.user.firstName = currentUser.firstName
req.session.user.lastName = currentUser.lastName
req.session.user.title = currentUser.title
req.session.user.location = currentUser.location
res.send(500)
```

But when I send the next request

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:2048/projects --cookie myCookie.txt
```

The `req.session` do not have the user that I had asssigned. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't express.session set the req.session.user automatically? If so it seems like a bad idea to overwrite it.

Comment: Its not doing it for me.. may be I am missing something. I am not doing .basicAuth() coz I couldnt figure out how to do it (I am a noob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was that I do not have the environment mentioned there. Changing line 5 it to:

```
app.configure('development', function () {
```

And it was all rainbows and butterflies after that.